# .Net Listbox DataBinding Problem

Tags: .net, data-binding, dataset

I have a main class which creates and populates a DataSet and an instance of this class is then passed to sub controls of my application by reference. I want to use this dataset to databind to components, in this case, a listbox. This is for a windows forms application.

Heres what I'm trying:

```
channelTypesLB.DataBindings.Add("Text", synData.ds, "ChannelTypes.channelType");
```

Note, I've also tried this: (not sure if theres a difference)

```
channelTypesLB.DataBindings.Add("Text", synData.ds.Tables["ChannelTypes"], "channelType");
```

Theres no errors and I do not see the data in the listbox... when I output `synData.ds.Tables["ChannelTypes"].Rows.Count` it tells me that there is in fact data in this datatable.

Am I missing something? I also trued channelTypesLB.Refresh(); after setting the databinding.

This may also be helpful... this is the code in my main class where the dataset is created, not sure if its maybe a scope issue, I'd imagine I would have received an error:

```
private DataSet _ds = new DataSet();
public DataSet ds { get { return _ds; } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the Listbox's DataSource rather than binding to the Text property:

```
channelTypesLB.DataSource = synData.ds;
channelTypesLB.DisplayMember = "ChannelTypes.channelType";
```

I'm not a DataBinding expert by any means, but I believe that by databinding the way you're currently doing it the control is binding to a `PropertyManager` which is used to bind one value of an object to one value of another.  By setting the `DataSource` it should bind to a `CurrencyManager` which is used to bind to a *Collection*.

[Here's a quick overview of WinForms databinding](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313482)

Comment: Hrmm that worked... used DisplayMember instead of DataMember... I would prefer the 1 liner of using DataBindings though

Comment: whoops, that was a typo--no such thing as a DataMember.  You can also build a `BindingSource`, which itself has a DataSource and DisplayMember (although they are accesible via constructor I believe) and set ListBox.DataSource = BindingSource

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming winforms here since there is no ASP.NET tag...

```
channelTypesLB.DataSource = synData.ds.Tables["ChannelTypes"].DefaultView;
channelTypesLB.DisplayMember = "channelType";
```

Just in case it is ASP.NET though try:

```
channelTypesLB.DataSource = synData.ds.Tables["ChannelTypes"].DefaultView;
channelTypesLB.DataTextField = "channelType";
channelTypesLB.DataValueField = "channelTypeId"; // I'm assuming this field exists, replace with your id field

channelTypesLB.DataBind();
```